# Where postgresql DISTRIBUTED BY setting stored?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to determine the characteristics of a ddl table without using pg_dump, but I can't find where the distributed by setting is stored in pg_catalog

Want to find table/view in pg_catalog, where DISTRIBUTED BY setting is stored

Comment: There is no `DISTRIBUTED BY` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: This looks like Greenplum, not PostgreSQL. You have to check the manual or ask the support team

Comment: yes, I realized that this is a greenplum setting. And there function pg_get_table_distributedby for that